# CakePHP: Paginação com query manual

Tags: php, cakephp

O [manual do CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) sugere uma alteração na paginação padrão para os casos de queries customizadas e em alguns casos no meu projeto tem funcionado perfeitamente. Porém estou com uma situação em que tenho várias queries customizadas e preciso fazer a paginação em todas elas (são relatórios bem específicos, que o padrão do Cake não me atende).

No caso do manual, ele informa a alteração somente para um caso específico, mas e nestes casos com várias queries, como proceder?

Exemplo de uma query customizada que estou utilizando:

```
    $data = $this->Negociacao->query('SELECT
        Consultor.nome,
        Cliente.nome,
        Negociacao.id,DATE_FORMAT(Negociacao.created,"%d/%m/%Y") AS data,SUBSTR(Negociacao.empresa,1,15) AS empresa,SUBSTR(Negociacao.assessoria,1,15) AS assessoria,
        Situacao.nome,
        CASE WHEN Negociacao.negociacao_status_id != 3 THEN
        DATEDIFF(NOW(),Negociacao.created) ELSE NULL END
        AS dias,
        CASE WHEN Negociacao.negociacao_status_id != 3 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),Negociacao.created) > 3 THEN "Y" ELSE "N" END AS atrasado
        FROM negociacoes Negociacao
        LEFT JOIN clientes Cliente
        ON Negociacao.cliente_id = Cliente.id
        LEFT JOIN negociacao_status Situacao
        ON Negociacao.negociacao_status_id = Situacao.id
        LEFT JOIN usuarios Consultor
        ON Negociacao.consultor_id = Consultor.id           
        WHERE Negociacao.consultor_id = '.$consultor.'
        ORDER BY data');
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o seu problema específico, e por que o método do manual não funciona no seu caso?

Comment: @bfavaretto, não funciona porque não atende meus critérios. Tem formatações, condições e outros que o básico do Cake não me fornece. Quanto ao explicar melhor, o que não entendeu? Preciso fazer a paginação em todas as custom queries e o manual do Cake não aborda isso, preciso saber como fazer.

Comment: @DaniloMiguel tem como você postar um exemplo de uma dessas queries customizadas que você está fazendo e o como está trabalhando com a paginação para podermos tentar entender melhor o que você já tem feito?

Comment: @TafarelChicotti inclui no corpo da questão um exemplo de query. Quanto à paginação, não estou fazendo nada ainda pois além da query de exemplo, tenho pelo menos mais 6 outras diferentes.

Comment: Qual a versão do cake que está utilizando?

Comment: @TafarelChicotti, uso a 2.x

Comment: A resposta do @gildonei foi perfeita

Comment: É, demorei pra voltar aqui :) Então Danilo, como você viu na resposta do @gildonei, dá pra evitar paginação customizada forçando joins ou usando o Containable behavior. Ainda assim, em certos casos pode ser necessário usar [isto](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@DaniloMiguel Para esta sua query, você não precisa montar manualmente, você pode criar virtualFields, ou usar no proprio "field" do seu find e usar o método padrão de find do CakePHP

Como não conheço o relacionamento entre suas tabelas, vou usar o paginate com joins, mas caso seus relacionamentos sejam do tipo Negociacao ***hasOne*** com Cliente, Situacao e Usuario (consultor) você pode usar o Containable behavior que fica mais bonito e com melhor resultado, além de trocar LEFT JOIN por INNER JOIN.

```
<?php
$this->Negociacao->virtualFields = array(
    'dias' => 'CASE WHEN Negociacao.negociacao_status_id != 3 THEN DATEDIFF(NOW(),Negociacao.created) ELSE NULL END',
    'atrasado' => 'CASE WHEN Negociacao.negociacao_status_id != 3 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),Negociacao.created) > 3 THEN "Y" ELSE "N" END'
);

$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Negociacao.id', 
        'Negociacao.created',   // Sugiro formatar na view, na hora de apresentar os dados
        'Negociacao.empresa',   // Sugiro formatar na view, na hora de apresentar os dados
        'Negociacao.assessoria',// Sugiro formatar na view, na hora de apresentar os dados
        'Negociacao.dias',
        'Consultor.nome',
        'Cliente.nome'
    ),
    'conditions' => array('Negociacao.consultor_id' => $consultor),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'clientes',
            'alias' => 'Situacao',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'Negociacao.negociacao_status_id = Situacao.id'
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'negociacao_status',
            'alias' => 'Cliente',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'Negociacao.cliente_id = Cliente.id'
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'usuarios',
            'alias' => 'Consultor',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'Negociacao.consultor_id = Consultor.id'
        )
    ),
    'order' => array('Negociacao.data' => 'ASC'),
    'recursive' => -1
);

$this->paginate('Negociacao');
?>
```

Comment: Excelente solução, @gildonei. Vou testar aqui e confirmo o resultado, mas acredito que irá me servir perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Perfeito, usando o `find()` como deve ser usado, não dou +2 pq não tem como. :D

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai um exemplo de código que talvez possa lhe ser útil, caso em outras situações não consiga usar o exempo do gildonei.

```
//Verifica a quantidade de itens a ser exibido na tela
if (isset($_REQUEST['rowCount'])) {
   $rows = $_REQUEST['rowCount'];
}

// Indica qual a página atual, será usada para calcular qual a posição de offset e limit (skip,take) utilizados.
if (isset($_REQUEST['current'])) {
    $current = $_REQUEST['current'];
    $skip = ($current * $rows) - ($rows);
    $take = $rows;
} else {
    $skip = $current - 1;
    $take = $rows;
}

//Guardando a query string
$query = '....';

//Descobrindo a quantidade de itens ao todo
$qtde = $this->Model->('select count...');

// Retorna a quantidade de itens apenas necessários para construir a página
$result = $this->Model->query('...'."limit $take offset $skip");
```

e daí o resto é contigo.